# How to run a Jenkins Pipeline when two triggers are successful

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Here is my Jenkins Pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    triggers {
        upstream 'Trigger1, Trigger2'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run this job only when **Trigger1 AND Trigger2 are SUCCESSFUL**, but currently any one of the above trigger launches the job. Is there a way to wait for the second trigger when one of them is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built way to do this. However, there is a different approach I can think of. In the downstream job, have a condition at the very start that takes the build number (which you can get with the inbuilt variable `BUILD_NUMBER`), and check to see if the number is even or odd. If it is odd, then finish the job without going any further. If it is even, then continue the full job.

So if the number is 1, for example, that means this is the first downstream trigger, so the job shouldn't be built. If it is 2, then this is the second time the downstream job is being called, so you can go ahead an d build it.

Of course, there can be other problems, such as failed builds adding to the build count. So this is just a starting idea.